# Sort list with specific order

Tags: python, list, sorting

I've two lists `unsortedList` and `basedList`, what I'm tying to do is sort the `unsortedList` based on the `basedList` order, here's an example :

```
unsortedList = [2, 7, 8]
baseList = [10, 1, 3]
```

The output should be **[8, 2, 7]**

The `unsortedlist` elements order should sort like the `basedList`  element, so if the i element of `basedList` is the max value the unsortedlist should start with the max value as well.

Another example :

```
unsortedList = [10, 12, 23, 0, 8]
baseList = [30, 7, 9, 10, 13]
```

The output should be **[23, 0, 8, 10, 12]**

Is there any method already exist in python can achieve my needs ?

Comment: Umm... is that the correct expected output? 7, 8, 2 or 2, 8, 7 makes sense but can't see how you'd end up with 8, 2, 7...

Comment: Didn't quite understand how number 2 was sorted, can you please give a naive implementation using if-else of the comparator logic you want to have?

Comment: Do you mean "I want to rearrange `unsortedList` using the index order of the rearrangement of sorting `baseList`"?

Comment: explain the relationship between `baseList` and `unsortedList` ?

Comment: I apologize I've edited my question

Comment: @kojiro yes, this is what I want, the `unsortedList` elemnts order should be sorted like the `basedList` elements

Comment: Okay, then I should have complained about asking an "implement this for me" question...  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
unsortedList = [2, 7, 8]
baseList = [10, 1, 3]

en=[i for i in enumerate(baseList)]

l=sorted(en, key=lambda x:x[1])

l2=list(zip([i[0] for i in l], sorted(unsortedList)))

l3=sorted(l2, key=lambda x:x[0])

result=[i[1] for i in l3]

print(result)
#[8,2,7]
```

Comment: Finally, someone understood my question

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without using zip and lambda:

```
unsortedList = [10, 12, 23, 0, 8]
baseList = [30, 7, 13, 7, 1]

#prep step: modifies the baseList based on how often a duplicate number appears
visited = []
for i, number in enumerate(baseList):
    visited.append(number)
    baseList[i] += visited.count(number)/len(baseList)
    
#main code
result = []
for item in baseList:
    idx = sorted(baseList).index(item)
    result.append(sorted(unsortedList)[idx])
    
print(result)
#prints [23, 8, 12, 10, 0]
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much, your solution is more simple

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI Feel free to accept the solution that works best for you.

Comment: Your answer works fine but if the `basedList` has two items with the same value, the output list will contain duplicated items example : 
`unsortedList = [10, 12, 23, 0, 8]
baseList = [30, 7, 13, 7, 1]` the output : [23, 8, 12, 8, 0]

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI. That's not a problem.  You can add code that preps the duplicate-containing baseList for the main part of the code.  See my revised answer.